# CSS opacity transition in iOS webview

Tags: ios, css, webview

I am currently developing an html5 app that will be displayed through an iOS webview. In order to use hardware-acceleration of the iPad, I have applied

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

to all elements that are animated. This works fine and I can see the difference, however, whenever en element has an opacity transition (ie; fade in / fade out), it is still quite choppy, even though the element has translate3d applied. Am I doing something wrong or is there a different approach to optimize opaicty transitions for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably using this:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try. Should I add it only to the parent div I am targeting to fade in/out, or to all it's children too?

Comment: just to elements with transform: translate3d(0,0,0);